# How to find nodes in an XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I have loaded the following XML file using `xml.Load("myfile.xml");` where `xml` is of type `XmlDocument`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <DTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" version="1.0">
        <Documento ID="E000000005T033F0114525415">
            <Encabezado>
                <IdDoc>
                    <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
                    <Folio>114525415</Folio>
                    <FchEmis>2021-11-02</FchEmis>
                    <FmaPago>1</FmaPago>
                    <FchVenc>2021-11-02</FchVenc>
                </IdDoc>
            </Encabezado>
        </Documento>
    </DTE>
```

How can I get `Folio`node?

I have tried with:

```
  xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/DTE/Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio");
  xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("DTE/Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio")
  xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//DTE/Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio");
  xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio");
  xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio");
  xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio");
  xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/DTE/Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio")
```

when I debug `xml.DocumentElement` I see that the element is `DTE` so I think `xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/Folio")` should do it.

When I get `xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild` I get `Documento` node.

With `xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild.FirstChild` I get `Encabezado` node.

With `xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild` I get `IdDoc` node.

If I use `xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.SelectSingleNode("Folio")`, returned value is null.

If I use `xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes`, I get the 5 elements.

Then I could use `xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes[1].InnerText` to get `Folio` value.

I can traverse the XML but, how can I do it to get the element directly?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use **LINQ to XML** API for your task. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

The provided XML has a default namespace. It needs to be declared and used, otherwise it is imposable to find any XML element.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filename = @"e:\Temp\jstuardo.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    string Folio = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Folio")
      .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

    Console.WriteLine("Folio='{0}'", Folio);
}
```

**Output**

```
Folio='114525415'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about LINQ with XML. Finally that way I could reach all specific nodes I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Xpath like below:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myfile.xml");
var node= doc.SelectSingleNode("Documento/Encabezado/IdDoc/[Folio='"114525415"']");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are *few* ways to make things up with your issue.

So, we have our XML:

```
const string MyXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>
                       <DTE xmlns=""http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte"" version=""1.0"">
                           <Documento ID=""E000000005T033F0114525415"">
                               <Encabezado>
                                   <IdDoc>
                                       <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
                                       <Folio>114525415</Folio>
                                       <FchEmis>2021-11-02</FchEmis>
                                       <FmaPago>1</FmaPago>
                                       <FchVenc>2021-11-02</FchVenc>
                                   </IdDoc>
                               </Encabezado>
                           </Documento>
                       </DTE>";
```

And we need to get `Folio` node (exactly node, not just value). We can use:

---

#### XmlNamespaceManager:

to find descendant node(s) through XML namespace (xmlns) alias in XPath:

```
// Creating our XmlDocument instance
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(MyXML);

// Initializing XmlNamespaceManager and providing our xmlns with 'SiiDte' alias:
var xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("SiiDte", "http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte");

// Declaring our simple shiny XPath:
var xPath = "descendant::SiiDte:Folio";

// If we need single (first) element:
var folio = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPath, xmlNamespaceManager);
// If we need all Folios:
var folios = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xPath, xmlNamespaceManager);
```

---

#### XDocument and its Descendants:

from `System.Xml.Linq` namespace and its `XDocument` class, to find descendant node(s) just by their tag name `<Folio>`:

```
// If we need single (first) element:
var folio = XDocument.Parse(MyXML)
                     .Descendants()
                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Folio");
                     // Add System.Linq using to access FirstOrDefault extension method
// If we need all Folios - just replacing FirstOrDefault with Where extension method:
var folios = XDocument.Parse(MyXML)
                      .Descendants()
                      .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Folio"); // and .ToList() if you need
// Or we can use also our XML namespace to filter Descendants:
var ns = (XNamespace)"http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte";
var folios = XDocument.Parse(MyXML).Descendants(ns + "Folio");
```

---

#### Deserialization:

to operate not with XML or nodes, but with some class (e.g. `DTE`), which represents your XML schema. I'm not sure that I totally understand your XML structure, but anyway as example it could be used.

So we create our classes, which are representation of our XML:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = nameof(DTE), Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte")]
public class DTE
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(nameof(Documento))]
    public List<Documento> Documentacion { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Documento
{
    [XmlAttribute(nameof(ID))]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(nameof(Encabezado))]
    public Encabezado Encabezado { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Encabezado
{
    [XmlElement(nameof(IdDoc))]
    public IDDoc IdDoc { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class IDDoc
{
    [XmlElement(nameof(TipoDTE))]
    public int TipoDTE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(nameof(Folio))]
    public long Folio { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(nameof(FchEmis))]
    public DateTime FchEmis { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(nameof(FmaPago))]
    public int FmaPago { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(nameof(FchVenc))]
    public DateTime FchVenc { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can easily create our `DTE` object with `XmlSerializer` class and its `Deserialize` method:

```
// Declaring our DTE object
var dte = (DTE)null;​
using (var reader = new StringReader(MyXML))
{
    dte = (DTE)new XmlSerializer(typeof(DTE)).Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Now we can get `Folio` as property of `IdDoc` class, which is property of `Encabezado` class, which in a turn is property of `Documento` class. Keeping in mind possible `null` result turns us to use, for example, `null-propagation`:

```
var folio = dte?.Documentacion.FirstOrDefault()?.Encabezado?.IdDoc?.Folio;
```

As `Documentacion` is a `List<Documento>` - we use again `FirstOrDefault` (also may be used `ElementAtOrDefault(0)`) to "imitate" `SelectSingleNode`. And for all `Folios` we can use `Select` (also with mull-propagation):

```
var folios = dte?.Documentacion.Select(x => x?.Encabezado?.IdDoc?.Folio);
```

Sure, we can edit properties if we want or add new:

```
// Edit
if (dte?.Documentacion.FirstOrDefault() is Documento documento)
    documento.Encabezado.IdDoc.Folio = 112233445566;

// or create and add new
var newDocumento = new Documento
{
    ID = "SomeID",
    Encabezado = new Encabezado
    {
        IdDoc = new IDDoc
        {
            TipoDTE = 123,
            Folio = 112233445566,
            FmaPago = 1,
            FchEmis = DateTime.Now,
            FchVenc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        }
    }
};
dte.Documentacion.Add(newDocumento);
```

And finally save back to XML file using Serialization. Here became usable our class and properties attributes (e.g. `[Serializable]`, `[XmlElement]` etc), which specifies how each property should be named or represented in XML:

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("My.xml", 
                                        new XmlWriterSettings 
                                        { 
                                            Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
                                            Indent = true 
                                        }))
{
    // We remove default XSI, XSD namespaces and leave only our custom:
    var xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("", "http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte");

    // and saving our DTE object to XML file.
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, dte, xmlSerializerNamespaces);
}
```

---

#### Remarks

Of course, parse of XML strings could be replaces with loading XML files (by `FileStream`s) if needed. And of course you can edit DTE (and child) classes with other properties and mark them as XML attributes or XML elements or making collections with `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes - whatever, depending on your needs. Also notice about `null` XML nodes or its values and take care about it with, for example, `Nullable<T>` (e.g. `long?`, `DateTime?`), `IsNullable` property of XML attributes and some kind of value validation at property setter:

```
 private long _folio;
 [XmlElement(nameof(Folio), IsNullable = true)]
 public long? Folio
 {
        get => _folio;
        set => _folio = value ?? 0L; // Null-coalescing with default fallback value of 0L
 }
```

Hope it would be helpful for your future purposes.